# How to receive the data from time to time from Firebase realtime database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am new in Java and Firebase. Currently, I doing a project which can send and received location from database from time to time. Now, I successfully upload the location to the database. However, I failed to receive the data from database from time to time.

Here is my code to receive the data from database.

```js
private void getUserLocation() {
        DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("UserID")
                .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("User location");

        ValueEventListener listener = databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                userlatitude = dataSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue(String.class);
                userlongitude = dataSnapshot.child("longitude").getValue(String.class);

                Double UserLatitude = Double.parseDouble(userlatitude);
                Double UserLongitude = Double.parseDouble(userlongitude);

                //String Userlatitudedouble = String.valueOf(UserLatitude);
                //String Userlongitudedouble = String.valueOf(UserLongitude);

                Log.i("user double latitude", userlatitude);
                Log.i("User double longitude", userlongitude);

                Double hostlatitudedouble = Double.parseDouble(latitude_host);
                Double hostlongitudedouble = Double.parseDouble(longitude_host);

                //String hostlatitudedouble = String.valueOf(HostLatitude);
                //String hostlongitudedouble = String.valueOf(HostLongitude);

                Log.i("host double latitude", latitude_host);
                Log.i("host double longitude", longitude_host);

                getDistance(UserLatitude, UserLongitude, hostlatitudedouble, hostlongitudedouble);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
```

So guys, how can I  do the changes so that I can receive the data from database every 5 seconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try running this:

```
new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
       Log.i("tag", "Fetching user location");
       getUserLocation()
    }
},0, 5000);
```

Just make sure you handle cases such as the response getting delayed over 5 seconds and meanwhile it's invoked 2nd time. That won't be a common case but just to be assured.